# Strip exif data from images

Tags: media

It seems most people rather keep the exif data, and have trouble keeping it. I have the opposite problem - we have a profile picture upload and it keeps the exif data. I'd like to strip that off the images. Is there a way to actively do that?

Comment: From original picture? Or from image styles? As a rule, Drupal does not alter user-uploaded files in any way, it only creates altered copies if needed, so this is a big difference.

Comment: The altered copies though do not keep the exif data.

Comment: Yes, from the original picture. I'd like the user to keep the opportunity to upload an image. Then I'd like to strip the exif data, and then use that version. It doesn't matter to me if I have to create a copy for it to work. The amount of pictures uploaded is fairly small.

Comment: @Wtower sometimes they do. It depends on the library that is doing alterations, and on the specific set of operations configured. It is a wide and interesting topic ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by implementing [`hook_file_presave($file)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_presave/7)

> This hook is called when a file has been added to the database. The hook doesn't distinguish between files created as a result of a copy or those created by an upload.

In this hook, you need to:

1. Test if file is really an image. I suggest using mimetype for this task: `$file->filemime`
2. Recognize which image processing library your Drupal is using. See [`image_get_available_toolkits()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!image.inc/function/image_get_available_toolkits/7), [`image_gd_check_settings()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!image.gd.inc/function/image_gd_check_settings/7) and [ImageMagick](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagemagick).
3. Process that file. This part is general programming issue [already well answered on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3614925/2389310) - I see no point in reposting it here, I think I covered Drupal part of the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Now, it looks like the easiest way to do this is with [File metadata manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_mdm) (Drupal 8 and above). It has a submodule file_mdm_exif, which allows you to read and write EXIF information for JPEF and TIFF images.

You would still need to add some custom code to automatically remove EXIF data before saving.

Answer (score 0):

To strip the metadata from image styles, you can use the [Image Effects](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_effects) module.  Install the module, go to the relevant image styles (`/admin/config/media/image-styles/manage/`), and then add the **Strip metadata** effect.